# 2010 Runtime/Access 2003

Tags: microsoft-access-2003, runtime

I see that Access 2010 Runtime and the Redistributable are free and say they will run .mdb files.  Does that mean that I can put the runtime and redistributable files on a client's computer and that they can then run Access 2003 programs (which link to MySql through ODBC)?